# Should Java automatically detect IPv4/IPv6?

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

I have a built-in PHP HTTP server started as

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

It apparently uses IPv6 for listening:

```
tcp6   0   0  ::1:8080    :::*    LISTEN      2642/php
```

Using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` I try connect to it. However I get the exception `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.

Once I do `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");` everything works, of course. This seems to be a hack to me, though. Java implemenation should have worked with default settings.

Question: Why Java hasn't detected proper Internet protocol? Is it a bug or is misconfiguration of my OS (Linux)?

Comment: This is a great question, I'd love to know why Java doesn't follow the existing conventions more faithfully.

It seems like these are reimplemented on each platform as rough approximates http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7120875/webrev.3/src/macosx/classes/java/net/DefaultInterface.java.html

Comment: hmm. Strange. [Gist: This program](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/a12c8c20f86d998474bb14d0e0b533cb) seems to work fine for me on the Mac (the server is using IPv6). And the said property is `null`.

Comment: What are the DNS records involved with this host? Could it be that it has an A record to a nonfunctional IP4 address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java (at least Oracle or OpenJDK up to Java 8) does not correctly implement address selection. I brought this up a while back on the [net-dev mailinglist](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/net-dev/2013-June/006553.html), but there was not much traction.

The default mode is to prefer dualstack/IPv6 address families but preferable connect to IPv4 addresses. This is what you can influence with the `preferIPv6Addresses=true`. According to the [(old) IPV6 guide for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/) this was a decision for compatibility reason.

In your case you could connect to "::1" IPv6 literal or add a now localhost6 alias (as it will also work with address entries which have no ipv4 address).

Especially for "localhost" a lot of missconfigured systems are out there, anyway.

Comment: I sent a reminder to net-dev http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/net-dev/2016-April/009680.html